# Differen precision in OffsetDateTime nanoseconds

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have to update one service to java 17 and spring boot 3 (from java 11 and spring 2.7.16)

But I faced with issues tests. A lot of tests have such checks:

```
@Test
void shouldGetFailure() {
OffsetDateTime processingTime = OffsetDateTime.now().minusMinutes(10);

saveDataToDataBase(event, processingTime, 0);

doSomeWork();

HashMap<String, Object> response = loadDataFromDataBase();
OffsetDateTime processingTimeFromBD = (OffsetDateTime)   response.getOrDefault(PROCESSING_TIME, EMPTY);

OffsetDateTime newProcessingTime = processingTime.plusMinutes(15);

assertThat(processingTimeFromBD).isEqualTo(newProcessingTime);
```

}

All of the tests failed with the same type of error:

> expected:
> 2023-11-21T08:08:23.**969519412Z** (java.time.OffsetDateTime) but was:
> 2023-11-21T08:08:23.**969519Z** (java.time.OffsetDateTime)

On my local Mac, everything works fine, but when I try to run this in CI with Ubuntu 20.04 all tests fail with such errors.

Of course, I can remove nanoseconds OffsetDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit...) but maybe exist another approach?

PS: tests use testcontainers with posgres db.

Comment: Your test is named `shouldGetFailure`. So is the error actually expected?

Answer (score 1):

## Java

Capturing the current moment with `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime` resolves to microseconds in any implementation of Java 9+ based on the [OpenJDK](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) codebase. In Java 8 specifically, milliseconds.

In all versions, those three classes are capable of *carrying a value* resolving to nanoseconds (9 digits after the decimal separator). But *capturing the current moment* (calling `.now`) is limited to microseconds/milliseconds (3/6 digits).

The hardware clocks on conventional computers are not capable of accurately tracking date-time to the nanosecond.

## Postgres

The date-time types in Postgres resolve to microseconds, not nanoseconds. So six digits only after the decimal separator, never nine digits.